# How to optimize the following Javascript code mention

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is the code I would like to optimise.
So, Question is that array in mention all value we need to check two value of sum is 8.
If, yes, then we need to find this value of index.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const sum = 8;

console.log(arr);
for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
    let cal = j + i;
    if (cal === sum && j !== i) {
      console.log(arr.indexOf(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions about improving working code are off-topic here. The question ***may*** be on-topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but be sure to [read their help before posting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Extra advice if you intend to at [codereview.se] can be found in [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778). Some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try this way

```js
 const arr = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5];
    const sum = 8;
    const indices = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const complement = sum - arr[i];

      if (complement in indices) {
        console.log(`Indices ${indices[complement]} and ${i} add up to ${sum}`);
        break;
      }
      indices[arr[i]] = i;
    }
```